# Get data from ajax with symfony

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony

Here my javascript function:

```
var lastid = 0;
function charger() {

    setTimeout( function(){
        $.post(
            'http://localhost:8000/chat',
            {id: lastid},
            function(data) {
                $('#chat').prepend(data);
            }
        );
        charger();
    },5000);
}
```

Here my .php controller:

```
public function addMessagesAction(Request $request){
    $id = $request->request->get('lastid');
    $idall = $request->request->all();
    var_dump($id);
    var_dump($idall);
}
```

and my result from var_dump:

> NULL
>   array(0) { }

my question is:

How to get my "lastid" in my controller ?

Comment: You send the `lastid` variable from your javascript called as `id`, so you won't get never `lastid` in you php code. If you want to get `lastid` you have to send it as `{lastid: lastid}` in your javascript code.

Comment: i have change id by lastid in my javascript file but the result is same...

Comment: Can you show us all the relevant code for the question? For instance, the routing configuratoin whill be very intersting.

Comment: Then marks @dragoste answer as the valid one in order to close the question.

Answer (score 3):

That's probably because yo've set in JS `id` param, not `lastid`. `lastid` is JS variable which is assigned to `id` param

```
{id: lastid}, //{name: value}
```

Therefore you should change it to:

```
{lastid: lastid},
```